# Why is `app.get('*')` always triggered?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Consider this little app:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/json", function(req, res){
  console.log("JSON route");
  res.json({foo: "bar"});
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  console.log("Slash route");
  res.send("Hello");
});

app.get("*", function(req, res){
  console.log("Star route");
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Listening.");
});
```

Whenever I go to either `localhost:3000` or `localhost:3000/json` in my browser, I can see from my server log that the star `*` route is also triggered. This is still true if it is changed to `app.get("/*")`

Why is this? I thought `res.send` and `res.json` halted execution.

Comment: You're going there in your browser, right? your browser is probably requesting a favicon.

Comment: @KevinB Son of a gun. If you post that as an answer I'll thumbs-up it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you request something with your browser, it will automagically try to request a favicon. Since your server doesn't have a route defined for a favicon, it goes to the `*` route, causing this confusion.

Comment: Might be worth `console.log(req.url);` if you want to see what is hitting the `*` route.

Comment: Thank you! This was so aggravating.